# perfect forward secrecy

Tags: ee2

I am trying to do perfect forward secrecy in an ExpressionEngine site. I have forced https to be used on all the pages using rewrite rules but the elements on the pages - images, js links, stylesheets etc - are coded using http and thus newer browsers give a message "Some unencrypted elements on this in the page have been blocked". The elements should be encoded with relative paths or with https absolute paths and are not. My developers tell me that they are encoded by ExpressionEngine and they can't change them. Is there any way to force ExpressionEngine to encode this in a more secure way.

Answer (score 1):

? This is a confusing question, simply because HTTPS is very easy to achieve with ExpressionEngine. You can absolutely run EE through HTTPS; find your site config under

```
Admin -> General Configuration
```

in your backend, and make sure this setting

```
URL to the root directory of your site
```

is set to an HTTPS address. If you are still having issues, it's most likely because of third party scripts being loaded via HTTP, or seriously incompetent/lazy developers you are employing. If it's third party scripts, you need to contact those vendors for information on how to access their content via HTTPS. If it's lazy developers, you need to tell them to stop hard coding URLS and use the

```
{site_url}
```

variable, which should be set to an HTTPS address. To be honest it sounds like incompetent/lazy developers.

Answer (score 0):

Change your file upload locations urls to https://
Make sure that your base site url is also set to https:// (admin / general config)
along with the control panel url
If you are loading anything external, think jquery,  make the call be src= " //cdn.jquery......."
any on server assets (style sheets, scripts, etc)  use {site_url}/path/to/asset  (you already set the site url to be https)
That should cover most of it.
If you view source of the page, and search for http:, that will tell you what is not being loaded under https.
Your developers are lazy.